# Vue SVG @click events

Tags: vue.js, svg

I am trying to load an svg but want my own vue click events.

I am using vue-svg-loader but can only use the onclick inside the svg

```
<a>
    <rect id="test" x="149.69" y="30.732" width="47.585" height="38.663" fill="#01ff00" onclick='console.log("Hello")' />
  </a>
```

I want to be able to use my own methods inside my file.vue

When I copy and paste the entire svg into my vue file without using vue-svg-loader then it works fine where I can use my own methods, however it takes ages each time to compile.

Is there a way to use my own methods a bit like so whilst using vue-svg-loader:

```
methods: {
    CheckOut() {
     console.log("item Clicked")
     alert("Item Clicked")
    },
}
```

my template looks like so:

```
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <br /><br /><br /><br />
    <v-row class="text-center">
      <v-col class="mb-4">
        <h1>This is an about page</h1>
     

  <PlanType class="logo" />
  </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </div>
</template>
```

and script a bit like so:

```
<script>

import PlanType from '../../public/PlanTypeA-1.svg';
export default {
  name: "About",
  components: {
    PlanType
   
  },
```

Comment: what about a simple img tag with src set to that svg file? then add @click event to the img tag.

Comment: you can use document.addEventListener in mounted for all SVG elements